# Where can I ask for free proofreading?

Tags: discussion, resources, online-resources

I know that proofreading is prohibited in this site. However, I'd like to ask if there are free online websites to do that.

I remember once there was a website where I can help people in Spanish/Portuguese and they help me in English.

I attempted searching on Google, but I didn't find anything.

Suggestions are highly appreciated guys.

Comment: Critique Circle

Comment: Some have recommended lang-8.com or italki.com in the past, though I have no firsthand experience with them. But please note that requests for resources are also off-topic :).

Comment: @choster you are the one, the website is lang-8. Anyway, it's good to check the other suggestions.

Comment: @sarah Did my sites work for you. The top two I would choose are paper rater because it

Comment: is free and accepts a full paper, and Online correction

Comment: @anonymous I'll check them once I arrive home. Thanks for the time you've dedicated to help me.

Comment: @sarah I have been thinking about asking this question for some time. Good that you did. Thanks :)

Comment: I love Grammarly a lot!

Comment: Try englishforums.com. They like to proofread.

Comment: If you already own a copy of Microsoft Word, or OpenOffice.org, it will do some proofreading automatically.

Comment: The short and unpopular response would be that if you need professional-quality writing, you should hire a professional-quality writer or editor, rather than cheap, anonymous substitutes. :)

Answer (score 5):

I have a few very reliable sources.

[Paper Rater](http://www.paperrater.com/)

[Grammar Check](http://www.grammarcheck.net/editor/)

[Spell Check Plus](http://spellcheckplus.com/)

[Polish My Writing](http://www.polishmywriting.com/)

and finally

[Online Correction](http://www.onlinecorrection.com/)

Comment: Are these for free or do we need to pay registration fee to get an account?

Comment: @JonyAgarwal You can use them for free with an accurate fix but some have an option for subscribing or using a more advanced fix. Paper Rater is probably the best one. Just click the free use.

Comment: Just tried it. Looks great. However, I still wish proofreading was available in EL&U. Some of the tips given after the review are pretty complex !

Comment: @JonyAgarwal You may be able to ask a specific question about a specific suggestion which has come from proof-reading. Possibly.

Answer (score 4):

**[Lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/)** is a good volunteer-based proofreading portal.

It works on the principle of reciprocity: you proofread a guy or gal's posts in your language, they proofread writing in theirs. Furthermore, the more you've proofread, the higher your reputation is, and this also attracts readers and proofreaders.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thank you! Feel free to proofread away my mistakes!

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer, now we'll be able to post a link to users who ask EL&U to proofread their work.

Answer (score 3):

You might try

```
englishforums.com
```

You'll need to create a free account. Click on "Forums", the rightmost item in the main menu and scroll down to

```
Essay, Report & Composition Writing
```

where you can post your text and people will give you advice even beyond simple proofreading.  The site also has an internal messaging system, which can be helpful for one-on-one conversations about your writing.  I don't know how many "editors" avail themselves of that facility.  I used to.

Answer (score 3):

Give [Typely](https://typely.com/) a try. It is a free proofreading application that you can use right away. It has been featured on the frontpage of many news aggregators and is already stable and strong.

[image]

Our main focus is not grammar but we do catch a lot of mistakes while performing **over a thousand checks** on any given document. You can also check your writing’s **sentiment, required education for audience (grade) or reading ease**.

Answer (score 2):

I use  >>

[autocrit.com](https://www.autocrit.com)
[grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com)
[editminion.com](http://editminion.com)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I usually use...

Reverso: http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/

Or...: https://www.grammarcheck.net/editor/

Answer (score 0):

Grammarly is a Chrome extension and [website](http://grammarly.com) that can check grammar for you. Note that it does not work in Google Drive apps. Finally, it can store documents on the webpage on your account.

Comment: You have a few typos there, mate. Should be "Grammarly is a Chrome extension and website that can't check grammar for you. Note that it does not work."