# Verification of the meaning for professional page

Tags: discussion, translation

I want someone to take a look and check if the meaning is correct. It's for a professionnal page so I need to be as good as possible...

[Note here, I get the point]

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because proofreading is off-topic on the main site *and* the same rule applies to meta. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your precious help :D

Comment: What you're looking for is the question [Where can I ask for free proofreading?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7571/191178)

Comment: Yeah, well you're not the first and you won't be the last to ask a group of anonymous people to  proofread a CV or an essay for free. How would you know if you could trust the first (and maybe only) user who posts an answer? You'd be surprised how many users misspell stuff even when spellcheckers aps are so easy to come by.

Comment: This time it's really helpfull. @Laurel Thank you :]